# Treating function as an object in Python

Tags: python

*I am not sure if the title will match the question I am about to ask but please feel free to update it if you know a better title which can help everyone.*

So let's say we have the following definition:

```
>>> def helloFunction():
        name = "Hello World"
```

so when I type in the following code, that returns an empty dictionary.

```
>>> helloFunction.__dict__
{}
```

I am not sure if this is how it should be but let's continue. Interestingly, I can do the following:

```
>>> helloFunction.hello = "world"
>>> helloFunction.__dict__
{'hello': 'world'}
```

and when I type in the following code, it tells me `helloFunction` is indeed a function.

```
>>> type(helloFunction)
<type 'function'>
```

I am coming from C# and this behavior is little odd to me. How come Python works like this? Is a function an object? How should I interpret this situation? And also where would I need this type of functionality?

### **Update**

While I was composing this question, I realized `__class__` is defined on `helloFunction`.

```
>>> helloFunction.__class__
<type 'function'>
```

So it seems like `function` is indeed a class type?

Comment: Functions in Python are considered first-class objects, meaning they are objects. In fact, if `x.__call__` method exists then `x()` is a legitimate call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pep 232](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) added "function attributes" to the language.  You can read that if you want all the official reasoning.  The reality of the situation boils down to this sentence in the intro:

> func_doc has the
>   interesting property that there is special syntax in function (and
>       method) definitions for implicitly setting the attribute.  **This
>       convenience has been exploited over and over again, overloading
>       docstrings with additional semantics.**

Emphasis mine.  People were using the `__doc__` attribute to smuggle all sorts of function metadata; it seemed more natural to provide a real place to do that.

As for some more specific questions:

> Is a function an object?

Oh yes.  Functions are first-class objects in python.  You can pass references to them as arguments to other functions all you like.  Were they not first-class, I couldn't do this:

```
def increment(x):
    return x+1

map(increment,[1,2,3]) # python2 `map`, for brevity
Out[3]: [2, 3, 4]
```

> And also where would I need this type of functionality?

You generally don't.  Not often.  But it can be useful when you want to store metadata about a function.

Say I wanted to wrap a function with a decorator that records how many times it's been called.  That's easy since we can plop that info into the function's `__dict__`.

```
def count_calls(func):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        before = getattr(func,'times_called',0)
        func.times_called = before + 1
        print('func has now been called {} times'.format(func.times_called))
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return _inner

@count_calls
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

add(3,4)
func has now been called 1 times
Out[7]: 7

add(2,3)
func has now been called 2 times
Out[8]: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A function is an object and - like most objects in Python - it has a dictionary. One usage example I've seen in the wild is with the web framework [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), where it's used to indicate which methods are to web access:

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True
```

When a path is accessed, the dispatcher can check that the corresponding handler method has its `exposed` attribute set to `True` and respond to it, allowing for both accessible and private methods to be safely defined on the controller.

Another use I've seen was a decorator that counted the number of times a function was called:

```
def call_counter(fn):
    fn.count = 0
    def _fn(*args, **kwargs):
        fn.count += 1
        return fn(*arg, **kwargs)
    return _fn
```

Answer (score 0):

Partly quote from Learning Python (Mark Lutz):

> Like everything else in Python, functions are just objects; they are
>   recorded explicitly in memory at program execution time. In fact,
>   besides calls, functions allow arbitrary attributes to be attached to
>   record information for later use.

```
def func(): ... # Create function object
func() # Call object
func.attr = value # Attach attributes
```